# Was the radio talk in "Right Here, Right Now" real or created for the song?

Tags: lyrics, fatboy-slim

The version of Fatboy Slim’s [*Right Here, Right Now*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_Here,_Right_Now_%28Fatboy_Slim_song%29) from the album [*You've Come a Long Way, Baby*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You%27ve_Come_a_Long_Way,_Baby) ends with this radio talk:

> **[Host]** [WBCN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WBCN_%28FM%29), and who’s this?
>
> **[Caller]** Hey, this is Brad, this is Brad, this is …
>
> **[Host]** Now uh, who's your, who’s your favorite artist, who do you wanna hear?
>
> **[Caller]** Well, uh, my favorite artist right now is Fatboy Slim, that guy kicks ass!
>
> **[Host]** How tremendous is Fatboy Slim?
>
> **[Caller]** The band of the nineties, if you wanna call it a band, because it’s a one man name.
>
> **[Host]** Wow … Fatboy, and you wanna hear that new Fatboy song?
>
> **[Caller]** Absolutely!
>
> **[Host]** Which one?
>
> **[Caller]** The umm …  it’s "funk soul brother, check it out!"
>
> **[Host]** Sing it, I don’t know which one!
>
> **[Caller]** "Right about now, the funk soul brother, check it out now, the funk soul brother"

(Corrections to the transcription are welcome.)

Was this scene made up for the song (so both the host and the caller play roles), or was this an actual caller on a real radio show (obviously edited after)?

If the former, who speaks the roles? If the latter, which radio show/host is this?

Comment: I had always wondered this and assumed it was acted, but a couple of sites out their claim it's real. I had no luck finding out who the DJ is though!

Comment: I think it's just created for the song. A more obvious example is the album created by Queens Of the Stone Age entitled Songs For The Deaf, which was full of radio talk in-between songs.

Answer (score 11):

It was real. The station, WBCN in Boston was an alt-rock station that was HUGE in the 90's but was shuttered in 2009, though it lives on online. Bradley Jay was a DJ and is currently a talk-radio host on Boston's WBZ AM 1030 from midnight to 4am. I actually heard this call live when it happened so I can confirm, it is legit. Bradley was a great DJ to listen to, good banter and did a lot of live and taped remixes for his shows.

Final sign off - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbkgYVJfey4

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WBCN_(FM)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the website for one of the two parties in the exchange is apparently [here](http://bradleyjay.com/performance-artist-bio/), but I have no idea which of the guys it is. His name is Bradley Jay, he claims to have been a DJ at WBCN, but the caller's name is also Brad...confusing to say the least. I would try to get in touch using the contact form given on the site, but I'd put money on the fact that it was probably recorded in the studio, not live.

Comment: Answers on StackExchange should have citations.  What makes you think it was recorded in a studio?

Comment: Bradley Jay's [resume](http://pointmedia.us/bradleyjay/wp-content/blogs.dir/20/files/2013/02/Bradley-J-Rez.pdf) states merely that he "can be heard on" the recording. Based on the editing of the caller saying his own name (the repeated "Brad") it was certainly modified within a studio, and from the clarity of both voices it doesn't sound like a tape dub or even a recording of a radio show.

Comment: The link to Bradley Jay's website seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Norman Cook himself explains how it went down on Twitter (see the thread): https://twitter.com/fatboyslim/status/1345131804232187905

From the thread on Twitter

> Fatboy Slim / @FatboySlim / 1 Jan 2021 "i went on WBCN when i was
> promoting 'rockafella skank' and they played me this tape of a guy who
> had rung in the day before. i thought it was so goofy and persuaded
> them to let me have the tape and let me put it on the album.. i
> subsequently met Brad next time i was in Boston and ...and he became a
> friend and drinking buddy......"
>
> also on same thread
>
> Bill Lichtenstein / @BLNYCNY / ·2 Jan 2021 "How do I hear it?  I was
> an announcer there and just produced the new award-winning doc on the
> early days of WBCN.."

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/12746)

Answer (score 0):

Fatboy Slim actually later met Brad (the caller), as was seen in a documentary made in 2001. It was called "We've Got To Get Out Of This Business" and was on Youtube at one point, but seems to have since been taken down.

Comment: Link to rather sparse [BFI catalogue entry](https://www.bfi.org.uk/films-tv-people/4ce2b86a37f6f) for the film